# Mysql won't connect to program VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have installed the mysql and connector but for some reason it won't connect to the database! I am trying to make a simple login system obviously with a mysql database I created with 000webhost.com but every time I try to log in I get the error of not being able to establish connection?

here is my code:

```
If username.Text = "" Or password.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a Username and Password")
    Else
        'Connect to Database
        Dim connect As New MySqlConnection("server=host;user id=dbuser;Password=pass;database=dbname")

        Try
            connect.Open()

        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MsgBox("Error couldn't establish a connection to the database")

        End Try

        'SQL Query to Get the Details

        Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim sqlquery = "Select * From User where username = '" + username.Text + "' And password = '" + password.Text + "'"
        Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
        myCommand.Connection = connect
        myCommand.CommandText = sqlquery


        'Starting The Query
        myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
        Dim mydata As MySqlDataReader
        mydata = myCommand.ExecuteReader

        'To check the Username and password and to validate the login 
        If mydata.HasRows = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Invalid Login")
        Else
            MsgBox("UserName N Password is accepted!")
        End If

    End If
```

Comment: So what happens if you actually look at the exception raised, instead of catching it and throwing away the information and instead displaying a meaningless "Couldn't establish a connection" message? Have you checked to make sure you're using the proper host, password, and database name? With no relevant error information and no way for us to troubleshoot your connection information, it's pretty difficult for us to assist. Stop discarding the exception information, use what it tells you, and verify the connection details.

Comment: I followed a tutorial to make this, I have no clue what your talking about. Yes all the information is right I triple checked it

Comment: I thought it was clear. **Remove** `Catch myerror As MySqlException` and the `MsgBox`, and see what the actual exception is. What part of that can you not follow? If *the information is right*, and you've *triple checked it*, what exactly do you expect us to help with? Contact the host of the database for support. We can't troubleshoot it from here, especially when your code intentionally says "Don't give me error info. Give me a meaningless sentence instead."

Comment: I am sorry I am new to this :/ this is what I got when I changed it to  Try
                connect.Open()
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try<

http://prntscr.com/6gxsua

Comment: Is this really a hardcoded string `"server=host;user id=dbuser;Password=pass;database=dbname"` or are you replacing the variables `host dbuser pass dbname` with correct values to connect to your DB?